# Setting sharedpreferences default value

Tags: android

I am using the following methods to save and read user settings:

```
    private void saveUserSettings(){
    SharedPreferences userSettings = getSharedPreferences("userSettings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userSettings.edit();
    editor.putInt("timeOne",timeOne);
    editor.apply();
}

private int getUserSettings(){
        SharedPreferences userSettings = getSharedPreferences("userSettings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        timeOne = userSettings.getInt("timeOne",timeOne);       
    }
```

Then in onCreate the following:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("userSettings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

This is fine and the data is saved when the app relaunches. However I want to have default data when the app is installed initially it seems to be that the values should be stored in an xml file.

I have created the following file under res/xml/preferences.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="timeOne"
        android:defaultValue="2"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Then in onCreate:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
```

I changed the "userSettings" to preferences to match up but this dosen't work and returns a value of zero. Is this method of reading the xml file ok or/and am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating yourself.

In this instruction the second parameter is the default to use if there is no shared preference with that name.

You just need to set that value to the default you need.

```
timeOne = userSettings.getInt("timeOne",<Put here the default value>);
```

**EDIT I**

Lets say the default value if it is the first time the app runs and there is no setting saved yet, is 2.

The method that reads the value should be like this.

```
private int getUserSettings(){
        SharedPreferences userSettings = getSharedPreferences("userSettings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        timeOne = userSettings.getInt("timeOne",2);       
}
```

Comment: That's a fair point but the issue is reading from the preference.xml file. It returns a 0 when it should be 2.

Comment: If 2 is the default value, why don't you set it like this then? timeOne = userSettings.getInt("timeOne",2);

Comment: I have added the example in Edit I

Comment: That actually makes things a lot easier. So what is the point in the preferences.xml file? Would i be right in saying that was how it was done in older versions? One last thing, when I build on my device each time my most recent preferences are saved, not the default ones, this is obviously to do with the file being saved on my local device. is it possible to destroy or clear this file so it is like a new install?

Comment: For development you can remove the app's data from Android's setting. That will also clear shared preferences.

Comment: Device must be rooted to access the data folder. Anyway uninstalling the app from the device before building deletes everything so is accomplished this way. Everything with regards to preferences seems to be all working ok. Thanks a lot for your advice.

Comment: You don't need a rooted device. You don't remove the file manually. You do it using android settings. Go to settings, go to application manager, find and touch the app, there you have a button to remove the application data. By touching that button you clear all the data asociated to the app including shared preferences. When you run the app it is like it was just installed.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful to know.